# Java networking example?

Tags: java, networking, network-programming

I am currently starting to learn the Java networking API with the help of the book "Introduction to Java Programming" by Daniel Liang. One example that appears is below. The idea is that there is a Server and a Client. The Client submits a radius value to the Server which computes an area of the circle from it and send it back to the Client. However, the code below(which I double checked) does not work.

**Client.java**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Client extends JFrame {
    private JTextField jtf = new JTextField();
    private JTextArea jta = new JTextArea();
    private DataOutputStream toServer;
    private DataInputStream fromServer;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Client();
    }   

    public Client()
    {
        //GUI
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        p.add(new JLabel("Enter Radius"), BorderLayout.WEST);
        p.add(jtf, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        jtf.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(p, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(new JScrollPane(jta), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        jtf.addActionListener(new TextFieldListener());

        setTitle("Client");
        setSize(500,300);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket("ip address of computer running server window", 8000);
            fromServer = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            toServer = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        }
        catch(IOException ex){
            jta.append(ex.toString() + "\n");
        }
    }
    private class TextFieldListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                double radius = Double.parseDouble(jta.getText().trim());
                toServer.writeDouble(radius);
                toServer.flush();

                double area = fromServer.readDouble();

                jta.append("Radius is " + radius + "\n");
                jta.append("The Area recieved from the server is " + area + "\n");
            }
            catch(IOException ex){
                System.err.println(ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Server.java**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Server extends JFrame {

    private JTextArea jta = new JTextArea();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Server();
    }
    public Server()
    {
        //GUI
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(new JScrollPane(jta), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setTitle("Server");
        setSize(500,300);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

        //Server Code
        try {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8000);//Establish this server with the port 8000
            jta.append("Server started at " + new Date() + "\n");

            //Allows server to listen for connections
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

            //Data streams for writing/reading data into the connected socket from above
            DataInputStream inputFromClient = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            DataOutputStream outputToClient = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());


            while(true) {
                double radius = inputFromClient.readDouble();
                double area = radius * radius * Math.PI;

                outputToClient.writeDouble(area);

                jta.append("Radius recieved from client: " + radius + "\n");
                jta.append("Area found: " + area + "\n");
            }
        }
        catch(IOException ex){
            System.err.println(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

However when I run this code and input a value for the radius, I get the following error message from the Client window:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Client$TextFieldListener.actionPerformed(Client.java:51)
    at javax.swing.JTextField.fireActionPerformed(JTextField.java:492)
    at javax.swing.JTextField.postActionEvent(JTextField.java:705)
    at javax.swing.JTextField$NotifyAction.actionPerformed(JTextField.java:820)
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.notifyAction(SwingUtilities.java:1645)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBinding(JComponent.java:2859)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyBindings(JComponent.java:2894)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(JComponent.java:2822)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6191)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2084)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4776)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2142)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4604)
    at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(KeyboardFocusManager.java:1856)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:722)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:1000)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:865)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:686)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4648)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2142)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2492)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4604)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:82)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:676)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:674)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:86)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:690)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:688)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:687)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

How can I fix this ?
Here is the link to pdf of the book that I got example from. Check Chapter 33, book pg 1180(pdf pg 1213):
http://ccis141.files.wordpress.com/2013/09/introduction-to-java-programming-comprehensive-9th-edition.pdf

Comment: Please mark line **51** in `Client.java`.

Comment: Its the line that is : toServer.flush()

Comment: Want to make sure. Is it exactly the way you run it: `Socket socket = new Socket("ip address of computer running server window", 8000);` or have you actually pasted a valid `IP` there?

Comment: I have the actual ip Address of the computer running the server part of this application. I also tested it on the same computer with this part replaced by "localhost"

Comment: Note that your code does not appear to consider threading issues, and will likely not work until it does.

Comment: If `toServer.writeDouble(radius);` did not throw a NPE then I do not think `toServer.flush();` would throw a NPE.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels This is the code from the book that I was reading(typed up by me). The book does not consider any threading issues ?

Comment: please double check what is at line 51

Comment: @ScaryWombat It is the toServer.flush(); line.

Comment: I yet to see a single programming book without any typos / errors in the published code.

Comment: In that case the code that you have posted in consistant with what you have running

Comment: I'm a bit confused here. In Client you attach a listener to `jtf`. However, when the event is fired you retrieve your text value from `jta`.

Comment: Terrible example. It should catch and report `EOFException` separately, without treating it as unexpected, and it needs to close the socket when `EOFException` or `IOException` is caught.

Comment: Here is the link to pdf of the book that I got example from. Check Chapter 33, book pg 1180(pdf pg 1213): http://ccis141.files.wordpress.com/2013/09/introduction-to-java-programming-comprehensive-9th-edition.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as the networking code goes, I don't see anything wrong here. Like one of the users mentioned, what is really happening is that your Client is not establishing a connection to your Server for some reason but still allows a user to submit requests. I suspect it has something to do with your `TextFieldListener`. Since you mention that this is your first time learning networking with Java, I recommend that you start without the fancy GUI's and use command line applications. This way you can focus more on the networking aspect rather than having to deal with the UI and the event handling(later on you can make it pretty). To this effect, I wrote out a non-GUI form of the Client that should still work with your existing Server(nothing wrong there).

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ConsoleClient {

    Socket connectionSocket;
    DataInputStream inputStream;
    DataOutputStream outputStream;
    Scanner input;
    double radius;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ConsoleClient();

    }
    public ConsoleClient()
    {
        input = new Scanner(System.in); 
        try 
        {
            connectionSocket = new Socket("Server IP", 8000);
            inputStream = new DataInputStream(connectionSocket.getInputStream());
            outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());

            System.out.println("Connection established !");

            System.out.println("Please enter a radius: ");
            radius = input.nextDouble();

            outputStream.writeDouble(radius);
            outputStream.flush();

            System.out.println("Data from Client send !");

            System.out.println("The area received is " + inputStream.readDouble());

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex + "");
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The variable `toServer` is `null`.

While it is initialized in the constructor, the `JFrame` is made visible for the user prior to the initialization of `toServer`. What likely happens is that the `Client` instance cannot set up the connection to the server and `new Socket("ip address of computer running server window", 8000)` is blocked, and will eventually time out.
However the UI is already running and a user can trigger requests already.

When the connection to the server succeeds the NPE does not occur and everything works fine.

A simple test would be to move the line

```
setVisible(true);
```

to after the initialization of `toServer`, in which case the Client Ui will only be shown when the connection succeeds and `toServer` is not null.

Comment: @ScaryWombat I've actually run the program, simulated and debugged the problem. When the server connects properly it works just fine. When the server connection fails, a premature request does indeed produce the given NPE since `toServer` is still `null`.

Comment: But why would `toServer.flush()` throw a NPE and not the line above it, `toServer.writeDouble(radius);`?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels It is `toServer.writeDouble(radius);` that throws the NPE.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels `toServer.flush()` cannot throw an NPE that results in the given stacktrace.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels It is obvious that the OP is wrong about which is line 51: it is obvious that the `flush()` cannot throw an NPE if the preceding `writeDouble()` succeeded; and it is also rather obvious that this answer is correct. Do we really have to belabour the point to this extent?

Comment: No, I'll retract my comments. My apologies.

Comment: @EJP Why is line 51 wrong ? I loaded the file up on TextWrangler, TextEdit, and XCode...line 51 is same for all of them ?